# How to pass the files using robot framework?

Tags: robotframework

How do I implement this curl command using robot framework?

```
curl -X 'POST' 'http://localhost:8089/upload_api' -H 'accept: application/json' -H 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data' -F 'fileName=@tests\\test.xlsx'
```

I tried this one

```
Set To Dictionary    ${file1}    fileName=tests\\test.xlsx
${response}    post request    ${url}    ${headers}    files=${file1}
```

but getting error as 'fileName parameter is required'

Answer (score 0):

If your curl command works, you should be able to run it with [Run Process](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/Process.html#Run%20Process) keyword from the Process library. Here is an example that i heavent tested:

```
***Settings***
Library    Process
***Variables***
${command}    curl -X 'POST' 'http://localhost:8089/upload_api' -H 'accept: application/json' -H 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data' -F 'fileName=@tests\\test.xlsx'

*** Test Cases ***  
test 
    ${result}    Run Process    ${command}    shell=True
```